# Error #14: Attempted write to read-only memory Mips Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

```
board_one:
    .space 3600

board_two:
    .space 3600

        set_boards:
        addi    $sp, $sp,-16    
        sw  $ra, 0($sp)
        sw  $s0, 4($sp)
        sw  $s1, 8($sp)
        sw  $s2, 12($sp)

        move    $s4, $s0
        la  $s0, board_one
        la  $s1, board_two
        li  $s2, 0
        mul $s3, $s4, $s4
        jal     set_zero_loop

        lw  $ra, 0($sp)
        lw  $s0, 4($sp)
        lw  $s1, 8($sp)
        lw  $s2, 12($sp)
        addi    $sp, $sp, 16

        jr  $ra

    set_zero_loop:
        beq $s2, $s3, done_looping
        li  $v0, PRINT_INT  # print generation counter
        move    $a0, $s2
        syscall 

        li  $s4, 5

        sw  $s4, 0($s0)
        sw  $s4, 0($s1)
        addi    $s1, $s1, 4
        addi    $s0, $s0, 4
        addi    $s2, $s2, 1
        j   set_zero_loop


    done_looping:
        jr  $ra
```

My issue happens when I try to sw. Says im trying to write to read only memory? Really confused. I put the addresses of the arrays into registers then try to iterate on them

```
    Error #14:  Attempted write to read-only memory

Fault address:  0040203c

Register contents:

 $zero: 00000000   $at: 00000000   $v0: 00000001   $v1: 00000000
   $a0: 00000000   $a1: 7fffeb8c   $a2: 00000000   $a3: 00000000
   $t0: 00000019   $t1: 00000000   $t2: 00000000   $t3: 00000000
   $t4: 00000000   $t5: 00000000   $t6: 00000000   $t7: 00000000
   $s0: 00400000   $s1: 00400e10   $s2: 00000000   $s3: 00000019
   $s4: 00000005   $s5: 00000000   $s6: 00000000   $s7: 00000000
   $t8: 00000000   $t9: 00000000   $k0: 00000000   $k1: 00000000
   $gp: 00000000   $sp: 7fffeae0   $fp: 00000000   $ra: 00402010
    pc: 00402040    hi: 00000000    lo: 00000019

Current instruction:    ae140000 (at 0040203c)

Decoded instruction:  sw    $s4, 0($s0) (0x400000)
```

Can someone help I have no idea why I can't put a words in here.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I had this

```
    board_one:
    .space 3600

board_two:
    .space 3600
```

Change to this

```
    .data
board_one:
    .space 3600
.text

.data
board_two:
    .space 3600
.text
```

Allocates space correctly so you are trying to write over your program while running.